# BPS Deployment to Tomcat or Other Application Servers

Tags: tomcat, deployment

I read in the knowledgebase/library instructions for deploying the BPS to Tomcat. I wanted to verify that in fact with version 3.0 (which include the Human Task component) this type of deployment will continue to be supported and all features and functions of BPS will operate as expected.

Answer (score 1):

We do not encourage installing WSO2 products on top of other AppServers, and we have decided to drop support for webapp deployment mode of the WSO2 platform & products from the next major release onwards.

The WSO2 platform is a fully-fledged Cloud native middleware platform. This means, the platform has its own set of complexities which are much greater than a typical webapp. Hence, installing it on top of different AppServers greatly limits the capabilities of the platform as well as introduces a lot of complexities when combined with the complexities of the host AppServer.